# Как правильно обрабатывать ошибки в rxJava 2?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Проект состоит из 3 частей `data ,presentation,domain`
В data есть репозиторий который получает данные трансформирует их в обьект для `domain` и в принципе все дальше не важно.Так вот как обработать ошибку если данные не пришли,Как вообще правильно обрабатывать ошибки в Rx ?код применрно такой

```
 @Override
    public Observable<AuthorizationModel> getPostById(String postId) {
          return restClient.getAutrorizationApi(postId)
                 .map(this.authorizationEntityDataMapper::transform)
                 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

Comment: При подписке на `Observable` в метод `onError` Subscriber'a будут лететь ошибки

Comment: @A.Shakhov  знаю а как его правильно обработать так и кидать по слоям до вьюхи?

Comment: Не буду тут расписывать про чистую архитектуру, советую почитать https://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/ и посмотреть код демонстрационного проекта в репозитории. Но в любом случае нужно передавать Observable, и обработку делать в презентационном слое, чтоб ваши вью меняли своё состояние в зависимости от логики отображения

Comment: @A.Shakhov вью должен  имет фабрику exception и не более а ошибки обработки должны быть в data

Comment: @A.Shakhov я его читал и гайды гугла тоже )ъ